# Date picker in BIRT 3.7 not working

Tags: jsp, report, birt

After using the following guide I am unable to get the date picker to work other than in BIRT's report viewer.

http://terrarum.net/blog/adding-a-calendar-widget-to-birt.html

Here is the extract from my FramesetFragment.jsp page

```
    <script src="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/js/jscal2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/js/lang/en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/css/border-radius.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/css/jscal2.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/css/gold/gold.css" type="text/css"/>
```

and this is the extract from my TextBoxParameterFragement.jsp

```
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" ID="isRequired" VALUE = "<%= parameterBean.isRequired( )? "true": "false" %>">     
    <%if (parameterBean.getParameter().getDataType()==7|| parameterBean.getParameter().getDataType()==4) { %>
    <button id="<%=parameterBean.getName()%>_button"><img src="birt/images/calendar.gif"/></button>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="birt/JSCal2-1.9/src/js/calendar-setup.js">
        Calendar.setup({
            trigger    : '<%=parameterBean.getName()%>_button',
            inputField : '<%=parameterBean.getName()%>',
            onSelect   : function() { this.hide() }
        });
    </script>

 <%
}
%>
```

All of the files are in the right place and followed the guide to the T.

I'm using BIRT 3.7.1, and like I said it works fine and I'm able to select date's in the web viewer, but not in HTML.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Viewer uses the FramesetFragment.jsp and the HTML view uses the RequesterFragment.jsp. If you update the RequesterFragment.jsp with the same code as what you added to the FramesetFragment.jsp it should solve your problem.  You'll still want to add it to the end of the HEAD tag.  I'd suggest also adding the code to the RunFragment.jsp as well.

Hope this helps